# Split text at character limit and return string array

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Using my cpp skills, I have developed the following old-styled recursive method to split the text into string array with nearest word break capped or limit by the character-count parameter ("limit"):

```
#see below for sample usage 
def split_at_limit(text, limit, result)
  slices = text.scan(/.{1,#{limit}}/m)
  return if slices.blank?
  first_slice = slices.first
  if first_slice.last == " " || (slices.length > 1 && slices[1].first == " ")
    result << first_slice
    slices.delete_at 0
    split_at_limit(slices.join, limit, result)
  elsif slices.length > 1
    first_slice_length = first_slice.length - 1
    appendix = ""
    i = 0
    first_slice_length.times do |i|
      break if first_slice[first_slice_length-i].chr == " "
      appendix = "#{first_slice[first_slice_length-i].chr}#{appendix}"
      first_slice[first_slice_length-i] = ''
    end
    first_slice = slices.first if i == first_slice.length
    result << first_slice
    slices.delete_at 0
    slices[0] = "#{appendix}#{slices[0]}"
    split_at_limit(slices.join, limit, result)
  end
  result
end
```

Its serving the purpose, but is there a better way (swift algorithm) to achieve the aforementioned goal?

**Edit:**

Sample usage

```
def datadump
return <<-END_TEXT
Suspendisse ut neque magna, nec elementum odio. Integer quis massa tortor, commodo tincidunt augue. Donec congue lacinia odio in aliquet. Ut vehicula elementum mi id lobortis. Sed eget pretium orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla vel velit hendrerit nisl facilisis gravida quis ac nunc. Morbi tincidunt ligula ut turpis faucibus placerat. Duis commodo turpis vehicula diam imperdiet eu sollicitudin erat luctus. Nulla facilisi. Aenean aliquam facilisis enim et ultrices. Nulla adipiscing semper massa quis egestas. Nam tempus suscipit semper. Suspendisse sed venenatis lacus.

  Phasellus ac tortor a nisi porttitor rutrum eu nec odio. Cras pulvinar, eros non faucibus semper, odio odio mollis justo, vulputate rhoncus odio justo id purus. Donec tincidunt malesuada enim, luctus tempor augue interdum id. Maecenas luctus imperdiet justo, ut vulputate turpis varius et. Nunc placerat pellentesque interdum. Pellentesque porta dignissim neque a dignissim. Mauris vitae nisi at tortor hendrerit accumsan in at est. Phasellus erat mi, eleifend eu imperdiet sit amet, accumsan posuere risus. Donec at faucibus libero. Proin lectus risus, aliquet a dictum nec, iaculis a diam. Ut velit nibh, ultricies eget convallis a, dignissim vitae tortor. Fusce sed lorem mauris, non gravida nisi.

  Aliquam malesuada cursus dui, in vestibulum lectus vulputate ut. Proin semper facilisis augue, ut imperdiet erat facilisis ac. Maecenas laoreet faucibus mi, ut mollis diam aliquet scelerisque. Praesent sit amet magna quam, nec auctor nisi. Cras tristique varius scelerisque. Donec vehicula lectus ac urna fermentum faucibus. Aenean nec augue vitae dui tristique luctus. Donec lacus leo, pellentesque ut aliquet vitae, eleifend bibendum neque. Vivamus id diam risus, et ornare magna. Praesent quam dui, congue ut cursus sed, egestas id tortor. Integer eget lacus purus. Sed fermentum convallis quam, sit amet dapibus mi tristique non. Donec vehicula ligula eget risus varius aliquam. Praesent ut odio eu sem mollis euismod. Donec egestas tincidunt dolor et imperdiet. 
 END_TEXT
end

puts split_at_limit(datadump, 40, []).inspect

#gives=>["Suspendisse ut neque magna, nec ", "elementum odio. Integer quis massa ", "tortor, commodo tincidunt augue. Donec ", "congue lacinia odio in aliquet. Ut ", "vehicula elementum mi id lobortis. Sed ", "eget pretium orci. Cum sociis natoque ", "penatibus et magnis dis parturient ", "montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla ", "vel velit hendrerit nisl facilisis ", "gravida quis ac nunc. Morbi tincidunt ", "ligula ut turpis faucibus placerat. Duis", " commodo turpis vehicula diam imperdiet ", "eu sollicitudin erat luctus. Nulla ", "facilisi. Aenean aliquam facilisis enim ", "et ultrices. Nulla adipiscing semper ", "massa quis egestas. Nam tempus suscipit ", "semper. Suspendisse sed venenatis ", "lacus.\n\n      Phasellus ac tortor a nisi", " porttitor rutrum eu nec odio. Cras ", "pulvinar, eros non faucibus semper, odio", " odio mollis justo, vulputate rhoncus ", "odio justo id purus. Donec tincidunt ", "malesuada enim, luctus tempor augue ", "interdum id. Maecenas luctus imperdiet ", "justo, ut vulputate turpis varius et. ", "Nunc placerat pellentesque interdum. ", "Pellentesque porta dignissim neque a ", "dignissim. Mauris vitae nisi at tortor ", "hendrerit accumsan in at est. Phasellus ", "erat mi, eleifend eu imperdiet sit amet,", " accumsan posuere risus. Donec at ", "faucibus libero. Proin lectus risus, ", "aliquet a dictum nec, iaculis a diam. Ut", " velit nibh, ultricies eget convallis a,", " dignissim vitae tortor. Fusce sed lorem", " mauris, non gravida nisi.\n\n      ", "Aliquam malesuada cursus dui, in ", "vestibulum lectus vulputate ut. Proin ", "semper facilisis augue, ut imperdiet ", "erat facilisis ac. Maecenas laoreet ", "faucibus mi, ut mollis diam aliquet ", "scelerisque. Praesent sit amet magna ", "quam, nec auctor nisi. Cras tristique ", "varius scelerisque. Donec vehicula ", "lectus ac urna fermentum faucibus. ", "Aenean nec augue vitae dui tristique ", "luctus. Donec lacus leo, pellentesque ut", " aliquet vitae, eleifend bibendum neque.", " Vivamus id diam risus, et ornare magna.", " Praesent quam dui, congue ut cursus ", "sed, egestas id tortor. Integer eget ", "lacus purus. Sed fermentum convallis ", "quam, sit amet dapibus mi tristique non.", " Donec vehicula ligula eget risus varius", " aliquam. Praesent ut odio eu sem mollis", " euismod. Donec egestas tincidunt dolor "]
```

Comment: Please show example(s) of the input string and the expected results. And have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: I guess what you want is to split the text into maximum-40-character long strings each. And each string has been split at a word boundary that is as close as possible to the limit (i.e. 40) but should not exceed the limit.

Comment: I'd probably want to split that method up into some smaller methods before trying to optimize it. And I'd probably use full variable names, not something like `ele`.

Comment: @Zabba, that is exactly I am trying to do and this algorithm is working fine. Just need little brainstorming to make it more tidier and faster for bulk data input. Also, I don't understand where did you get that error: "data too long" ? I am testing this method in a simple rails application and its working perfectly fine even with the data returned by datadump. @Andrew Grimm, nice tips there. I have now changed the variable names to full/meaningful/descriptive ones.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that:

> You want is to split the text into maximum-40-character long strings each. And each string has been split at a word boundary that is as close as possible to the limit (i.e. 40) but should not exceed the limit.

Here is one solution:

```
def datadump
  return <<-END_TEXT
Suspendisse ut neque magna, nec elementum odio. Integer quis massa tortor, commodo tincidunt augue. Donec congue lacinia odio$
  END_TEXT
end

a = datadump.split(/(.{1,40}\b)/)
a = a.reject{|el| el.size == 0}
puts a # or p a  to see results
```

Comment: With your technique, the string gets split at every newline char. That should not be the case, I am letting the entire text as is, splitting it w.r.t the value of limit parameter AND making the string of maximum words that can get fit within this limit.

Comment: I don't see that problem (Ruby 1.8.7). Try using the `m` regex option so that the `.` matches new-lines as well.

Comment: can you provide the complete regex expression?

Comment: Can you show some sample input (and the output) that is causing a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a word wrapping algorithm.

A solution to this is shown [here](http://codeidol.com/other/rubyckbk/Strings/Word-Wrapping-Lines-of-Text/).

A comprehensive explanation of the regular expression is [there](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/wrapping-text-with-regular-expressions/)

[word_wrap](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-word_wrap) implementation from Ruby On Rails.